# WordPress keeps resizing my 947x947 image down to 500x500 (full-size option)

Tags: images

This is driving me crazy. The code for the image is: `<img src="MYLINK" />`

Yet it keeps resizing my image down to 500x500 from 947x947. How do I fix this?

Also, it disregards the image map I have which lets you click on different parts of the image to go to different sites.

EDIT: This is what I'm referring to: http://macaulay.cuny.edu/eportfolios/menatwork/test-page/
Right click and check the image properties: it shows how the 947x947 has been scaled to 500x500.

Comment: So... this is code you have in the post editor?

Comment: the link to the image is in the MYLINK. But yes that is the code.

Comment: I feel it has something to do with either Wordpress or the theme that I'm using (sliding door).

Comment: If you visit the post on your website, and you view the source of the webpage, is the code the same?

Comment: The cap on the image is a width of 500px. I was able to do everything I need, so long as I use an image of 500px width. This is a huge compromise, as this is the splash page for the site.

Comment: Can you please send the site url so that the problem can be Identified

Comment: Please check the original question for a site url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The hint from user29296 is what led me to this: I had to insert the image using CSS, not html. Check the page now: http://macaulay.cuny.edu/eportfolios/menatwork/test-page/

The code was this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#image
{
position:absolute;
width:947px !important;
height:947px;
background-image:url('http://macaulay.cuny.edu/eportfolios/menatwork/files/2013/05/test.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
</style>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading the image via Wordpress's Media Manager, goto 'Settings > Media' in your admin panel and configure the max dimensions for the 'Large' images uploaded via this.

Comment: The max dimensions in the Settings>Media are 1024x1024, which is larger than what I need. Regardless, wordpress scales down the image.

Comment: There's a basic generic css overriding your image size : line 758 of your style.css
`#content img {
height: auto;
max-width: 500px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}`
Your problem comes from here.

Comment: user29296 is correct - it is the max-width in your CSS causing this now we've seen the site.

Comment: how would I change that? I don't think I have access to the CSS. Is it possible for me to include overriding css on my page?

Comment: You will have access to the CSS, it's part of your Wordpress theme. You'll need FTP access to your WP install (you'd need to contact your web host if you don't). Unless the installer has applied read/write access to the theme's files, and then you'd be able to edit the CSS from the Appearance > Editor menu.